# IIS does not listen to its IP address, This page cannot be displayed

Tags: iis

We have configured multiple sites on an IIS server before, but now we cannot get a second site to work. IIS is installed on a virtual windows machine, and the ethernet adapter has multiple IP addresses assigned.

The second site on IIS has a binding to one of these IP addresses, which can be pinged fine, but the site cannot be reached.

I clicked Start, and the IIS site icon is missing the black dot that indicates Stopped.

The browser says: `This page cannot be displayed` with the suggestion to check the IP address.

With `netstat` I found out that no process is listening on the new IP address, which clearly is a problem.

We already tried with restarting IIS, and rebooting the entire virtual windows machine after creating the new IP address and new IIS site.

How do I get IIS to start listening on the IP address that its second site is assigned to?

Comment: A handy tool to diagnose "cannot be read" is: `telnet your-ip 80` as it detects if a listener can be reached. Also to detect firewall problems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Our sysadmin found the answer. IIS defaults to listening to all IP addresses, except if this list is empty: `netsh http show iplisten`

If that list is not empty, because someone configured one or more IP addresses in that list, you need to add the new IP address also, with, e.g.: `netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=172.16.1.52`

It will probably also work if you just delete all IP addresses from that list...

[More about `netsh`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307236(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: This was incredibly helpful